# Div does not insert into parent div

Tags: html, css, parent

I made this html css file . I want to put the yellow div (id=map) into parent div (id=main) but this yellow div does not go into parent div . I do not know what to do . please help me how to fix this problem .

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>My Real Project</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #container{
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        #header{
            position:relative;
            width:1000px;
            height:170px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color:lightgreen;
        }
        #footer{
            position:relative;
            width:1000px;
            height:170px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color:lightblue;
            bottom:0;
        }
        #main{
            position:relative;
            width:1000px;
            height:600px;
            background-color:darkred;
            margin: 0 auto;
            z-index:1;
        }
        #tools{
            position:relative;
            left:0;
            background-color:orange;
            width:260px;
            height:100%;
            z-index:2;
        }
        #map{
            position:relative;
            right:0;
            width:740px;
            height:100%;
            z-index:2;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">Place the header here</div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="tools">Tools</div>
            <div id="map">Map</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Place the footer here</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you put the code that you have?

Comment: I put it . excuse me . I was editing

Comment: The problem is with the `#main` you set a height of `600px` and if you want to set the child container into its parent you need to change the parent's height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use position relative its not work `left: 0;` you can set float to them: 

like this:

```
    #tools{
        background-color:orange;
        width:260px;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
    }
    #map{
        width:740px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:yellow;
        float: left
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add `float:left` in your `tools` and `map` CSS:

```
#tools{
        position:relative;
        left:0;
        background-color:orange;
        width:260px;
        height:100%;
        z-index:2;
        float:left;
    }
    #map
    {
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        right:0;
        width:740px;
        height:100%;
        z-index:2;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrv19k44/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try `min-height:600px;` inside `#main{}`

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/0dono2hL/)

css

```
    *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #container{
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        #header{
            position:relative;
            width:1000px;
            height:170px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color:lightgreen;
        }
        #footer{
            position:relative;
            width:1000px;
            height:170px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color:lightblue;
            bottom:0;
        }
        #main{
            position:relative;
            width:1000px;
            height:600px;
            background-color:blue;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #tools{
            position:relative;
            left:0;
            background-color:orange;
            width:260px;
            height:100%;
            float:left;
}
        #map{
            position:relative;
            right:0;
            width:740px;
            height:100%;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
#footer{
    background-color: red;
}

div.inner-div{
    float:left;
}


<div id="container">
        <div id="header">Place the header here</div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="tools" class="inner-div">Tools</div>
            <div id="map" class="inner-div">Map</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Place the footer here</div>
    </div>
```